# How send android object list using jsonParser.makeHttpRequest to PHP script

Tags: php, android

I am using jsonParser.makeHttpRequest to send variables from android app to PHP script. For example:

```
String url = "http://www.serwer17.com/script.php";
// Building Parameters
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userID", userID));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userName", userName));
// getting JSON Object
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url,"POST", params);
```

In my android app I have class:

```
class User
{
   int userAge;
   String userName;
   String userAddress;
}
```

I need to send to php script at once three variables:

```
   List<User> users
   int intValue
   String stringValue
```

How can I send these variables to PHP script?
Can I use jsonParser.makeHttpRequest like before?

Thanks for help

Comment: and what the heck is jsonParser.makeHttpRequest? why we should know this (besides terrible androidhive's so called tutorial? `String method; /*...*/
 if(method == "POST"){` hahahahaha, this guy don't know what he is doing)

Comment: I know that using the JSON format I can send just Strings. That's why I am asking what is the most efficient way to change object to String and send this String using JSON format as parameters. I am totaly new in case of PHP. My expiriance with android is half year :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to send three parameters from question to PHP script.
Andriod App side:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
for(int i=0; i<users.size(); i++)
{
    User userX = users.get(i);
    JSONObject jsonX= new JSONObject();
    try {
            jsonX.put("userAge", Integer.toString(userX.userAge));
            jsonX.put("userName", userX.userName);
            jsonX.put("userAddress", userX.userAddress);

            jsonArray.put(jsonX);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject();
try {
        jsonObject.put("intValue", Integer.toString(intValue));
        jsonObject.put("jsonArrayX", jsonArray);
        jsonObject.put("stringValue", stringValue);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

String url = "http://www.serwerx/example.php";

// Building Parameters
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("post", jsonObject.toString()));
// getting JSON Object
// Note that create product url accepts POST method
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", params);
```

PHP Script site:

```
if(isset($_POST['post']))
{
    $postX = htmlspecialchars_decode(htmlentities($_POST['post']));

    $post_x = json_decode($postX, true);


    //to get received string value or int value
    $intValue = $post_x['intValue'];
    $stringValue = $post_x['stringValue'];

    //to display received json array 
    $jsonArray_size = count($post_x['jsonArrayX']);
    for($i=0; $i<$jsonArray_size; $i++)
    {
        echo $post_x['jsonArrayX'][$i]['userAge'];
        echo $post_x['jsonArrayX'][$i]['userName'];
        echo $post_x['jsonArrayX'][$i]['userAddress'];
    }

}
```